# Box2D add a test

Tags: c++, box2d

Im follwing [this](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/making-a-test) very nice tutorial on how to create a test in box2D. I could run the testbed project and had no problems so far.
I right clicked on Tests and clicked add new item. there i created FooTest.h and copied the code from the tutorial.
[image]
Unfortunately i get an error while hovering over Test saying no class or struct name. I viewed the sources of the other .h file and dont see anything that shows that i need to include another file or do something else. I rebuilt the project several times.

My TestEntries file:

[image]

What did i do wrong? Should ive created FooTest.h in a different way?

Comment: What is the path to `FooTest.h` compared to the other files? You may need to do `#include "../foofolder/FooTest.h"` or similar to get your preprocessor to be able to find it (or add the folder in which the file resides to your include folders in the makefile).

Comment: @sonicwave i checked the other files f.e, slidercrank.h is located at C:\projects\Box2D\Testbed\Tests my FooTest.h is  at C:\projects\Box2D\Build\vs2013\FooTest.h. When placing footest.h  in C:\projects\Box2D\Testbed\Tests  the #include works but i get an error when building : 'FooTest' : is not a class or namespace name

Comment: According to the tutorial, FooTest.h should be in the Testbed/Tests folder too. Try moving it in there and see if it helps...

Comment: @sonicwave When placing footest.h in C:\projects\Box2D\Testbed\Tests the #include works but i get an error when building : 'FooTest' : is not a class or namespace name. FooTest.h got an exact copy of the tutorial and ontop got a 
#include "C:\projects\Box2D\Testbed\Framework\Test.h"

Comment: You could try stripping your FooTest class down to the bare minimum (eg, an empty class), to see if that changes the error (you should then get something about create not being a member of FooTest) - otherwise you might have multiple versions of the file and the preprocessor is picking up the wrong one maybe?

Comment: @sonicwave If you add an answer that advices to check the path i accept as answer, Got it working thanks a ton !

Comment: Good you got it working - I'll add an answer then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your `FooTest.h` is in the wrong place. According to the linked tutorial, `FooTest.h` should be in the `Testbed/Tests` folder. Make sure that it is in the correct place, and move it in there if it isn't.